# Custom UIInputView presented on inputAccessoryView not respecting height constraint on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I am building a chat application that has a floating text input field at the bottom of the screen (similar to the iMessage app).

[image]

I've achieved this by creating a `ChatInputViewController` which is a subclass of `UIInputViewController`, which contains a `UIInputView` with a `textView` for input.

In my main `ChatViewController`, I then override the following properties to present my custom `UIInputViewController`:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    override var inputAccessoryViewController: UIInputViewController? {
        return chatInputViewController
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    ...

}
```

Here's the issue: I also have a custom input view which is presented when the user taps on the help icon. The custom input view is laid out using Autolayout and has an explicit height constraint set to be equal to the height of the keyboard. When presented, this view swaps out with the keyboard in place. I am doing this by setting the `inputView` property of the `textView` and then calling `textView.reloadInputViews()`. This works as intended on all devices except the iPhone X, where instead the inputView is expanded to cover the entire screen.

[image]

There are no autolayout constraints logged in the console. Both the `ChatInputViewController` and `HelpInputViewController` have `allowSelfSizing` enabled on their `inputView`s and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` disabled. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.